# Jasmine - spy on "new myFunction()" not being called

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a mock module:

**Observable.js**

```
define([], function() {
    const Observable = function(data) {
        console.log('called'); /* <-- this is shown in console */
        this.data = data;
    };
    return Observable;
});
```

Which is called from my file **myFuncs.js**

```
createNewObservable: function(values) {
    return new Observable(values);
},
```

**I'm trying to test like this:**

```
describe('createNewObservable', () => {
    it("calls Observable", () => {
        window.Observable = Observable;
        const observableSpy = spyOn(window, 'Observable');
        myFuncs.createNewObservable(123);
        expect(observableSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The spy is not called and results in test fail

> Expected spy Observable to have been called

As mentioned above, the console log is seen so the function is called, I'm clearly spying on it wrongly.

**How can I spy on it to be able to capture the call?**

Answer (score 1):

Pretty interesting question as for me.

The reason why it is not working - because you actually **not** calling a spy. You call real observable from the module. And I think you can't achieve what you want directly.

But there is an option - you can modify your createNewObservable function to take a factory as a second argument. So, the result will be like here (simplified)

```
describe('my test', () => {

    const Observable = function (data) {
        this.data = data;
    };

    function createNewObservable(values, observer = Observable) {
        return new observer(values);
    }

    it("calls Observable", () => {
        const spy = jasmine.createSpy();
        createNewObservable(123, spy);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

})
```

Hope this helps, at least a bit

Comment: Hmmm - interesting approach but I don't really want to start modifying every method in the codebase that uses e.g. `new whatever()` - appreciate the answer though

Comment: Yep, that's why I will wait for another answer with interest)